# trying to use username in urlpattern to give every user a unique link

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

this my approach if you know how to do it please help

my views.py

```
def profile(request, username):
    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

# Template Urls!
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('Skolar/',views.base, name= 'base'),
    path('Register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/', views.my_login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
    path('<slug:username>',views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('EditProfile/',views.update_profile,name='editprofile'),
]
```

error showing

```
Reverse for 'profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<username>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

in my html i use

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:profile' %}">My Account</a>
```

adding profile html which i want ot show user after clickin gon that link

```
{% extends 'masteraccount.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static  'css/accountscss/profile.css'%}">
<div class="">
<div class="page-content">
  <label class="name" for="NAME">NAME:</label>
  <p>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</p>
  <label for="Email">Email:</label>
  <p>{{user.email}}</p>
  <label for="Twitter">Twitter:</label>
  <p>{{user.profile.twitter}}</p>
  <label for="Facebook">Facebook:</label>
  <p>{{user.profile.Facebook}}</p>
  <label for="Facebook">About:</label>
  <p>{{user.profile.about}}</p>
  <label for="Facebook">Date of Birth:</label>
  <p>{{user.profile.dob}}</p>
</div>
<a href="{% url 'accounts:editprofile' %}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Edit Profile</button> </a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: your url expects an argument pass it like so `{% url 'accounts:profile' request.user.username %}`. or `{% url 'accounts:profile' context_variable_having_username %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py let us assume your model is 'Profile' and your have 'user' related to one-to-one to User  you should use something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404

def profile(request, username):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,user = username)
    return render(request, 'profile.html',{'profile':profile})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

# Template Urls!
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('Skolar/',views.base, name= 'base'),
    path('Register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/', views.my_login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
    path('<slug:username>/',views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('EditProfile/',views.update_profile,name='editprofile'),
]
```

html

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:profile' request.user.username %}">My Account</a>
```

Note:it is always better to use pk for the profile.but slug it is also fine